Prove $\forall x \forall y(xEy \rightarrow \neg x=y)$ in the vocabulary of graphs
Problem: Prove the sentence $\forall x \forall y(xEy \rightarrow \neg x=y)$ in the vocabulary of graphs using the axioms of graph theory.
So far: The axioms of graph theory given are antireflexivity and symmetry. Here $xEy$ means there's an edge between the vertices $x$ and $y$. We were told we'd need identity axioms for this as well. Simply working backwards from the conclusion I've ended up at $\neg x=y$ and I know I need to assume $xEy$. The claim is obvious, but I can't formulate it using natural deduction. I'd appreciate an answer using a proof tree.
Slight update: Assuming $xEy$ and $x=y$, we deduce $xEx$, but by antireflexivity this is a contradiction, so we can eliminate $x=y$ and introduce a negation, so we have $\neg x=y$. Then we introduce the implication $xEy \rightarrow \neg x=y$ and eliminate the assumption $xEy$ (?) Then finishing off, we introduce the quantifiers (?).
Further update: Is this correct? Apologies for the image, MathJax doesn't support the package I use.


Antireflexivity states that $$\forall x(\neg x Ex).$$
Try to show that this is equivalent to $$\forall x\forall y(x=y\to\neg xE y).$$ The implication in this statement is the contrapositive of the one you want. Are you familiar with contrapositives in natural deduction?


Further update: Is this correct?
$\large\qquad\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{[x=y]^2\quad[xEy]^1}{x=y\land xEy}{\land\mathrm I}}{xEx}{\land\mathrm E}\quad\dfrac{\forall x~\neg xEx}{\neg xEx}{\forall\mathrm E}}{xEx\land\neg xEx}{\land\mathrm I}}{\neg(x=y)}{\neg\mathrm I_2}}{xEy\to\neg(x=y)}{{\to}\mathrm I_1}}{\forall y(xEy\to\neg(x=y))}{\forall\mathrm I}}{\forall x\forall y(xEy\to\neg(x=y))}{\forall\mathrm I}$

Mostly.  The inference of $\dfrac{x=y\land xRy}{xEx}$ should be attributed to $\,{=}\mathrm E$.
